# Range-for loop recognizes wrong type (C2440)

Tags: c++, for-loop, syntax, stl

The C2440 error (cannot convert from 'char' to 'Text_iterator' is occurring on this line):

```
void print(Document& d)
{
    for (Text_iterator p : d) cout << *p;
}
```

Replacing 'Text_iterator' with 'auto' gives the 'illegal indirection' error (dereferenced type must be a pointer).

Class Document has begin() and end() functions defined (returning Text_iterator), and Text_iterator has the usual iterator operators. Here is the code:

```
class Text_iterator
{
    list<Line>::iterator ln;
    Line::iterator pos;
public:
    // . . .

    char& operator*() { return *pos; }
    Text_iterator& operator++();

    // . . .
};
```

And Document:

```
struct Document
{
    list<Line> line;

    Text_iterator begin()
    {
        // . . .
    }

    Text_iterator end()
    {
        // . . .
    }

    // . . .
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the incorrect type for the loop variable.  The variable is not the iterator of the container but it is what the iterator of that container points to.

If you had

```
std::vector<int> foo(10);
```

And you want to use a ranged based for loop you would use

```
for (int e : foo) // or for (auto e : foo) 
    std::cout << e << " ";
```

You would not use

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator e : foo)
    std::cout << *e << " ";
```

So you need to use whatever `Text_iterator` points to instead of `Text_iterator`.  In this case

```
void print(Document& d)
{
    // if p is cheap to copy
    for (auto p : d) cout << p;
    // if p is expensive to copy
    for (const auto& p : d) cout << p;
}
```

should work.

Comment: Or (better IMHO) `for (const auto& p : d) cout << p;`. `const auto&` should be your "go-to" unless you need to modify the element or really want a copy - in many/most cases you don't.

Answer (score 3):

The [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) iterates over the content of a container.  So it's not about iterators, but dereferenced iterators.

Your code should be:

```
void print(Document& d)
{
    for (auto c : d) cout << c;
}
```

or if you really want to keep control over the iterators:

```
void print(Document& d)
{
    for (auto p = d.begin(); p!=d.end(); p++) cout << *p;
}
```

Comment: And if `p` is of a custom iterator type, then `++p` may be preferable (in any case a good default habit).